# Meteor / Magnific Popup : Catching popup DOM events

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, popup, magnific-popup

I am not sure what is going wrong here, so please help me SO God :)

I am setting up [MagnificPopup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) within a Meteor's application, so it responds to clicks on the `.popup_trigger` classed links, as follows :

```
 // POPUPS
  L.P_CONT.magnificPopup({
    delegate:   'a.popup_trigger', 
    type:       'inline',
    prependTo:  "#page_content",// That is where Meteor puts his
  });
```

Here is an exemple of some template implementing a `.popup_trigger` link, which is working great, meaning that the popup triggers correctly :

```
<template name="booking">

  <p>{{_ 'I have a '}}<a class="popup_trigger" href="#promocode">{{_ 'promocode'}}</a></p>

  <div id="promocode" class="mfp-hide">
    <h1>{{_ 'Voucher'}}</h1>

    <form id="promocode_form">
      <input type="text" name="promocode" placeholder="{{_ 'Promocode'}}"/>
      <input id="cancel" type="submit" name="cancel" value="{{_ 'Cancel'}}"/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="{{_ 'Submit'}}"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

You may have noticed the `prependTo:  "#page_content"` option I am passing to `magnificPopup`. This tell him to prepend the popup element to `#page_content`, which is the enclosing element of my Meteor templates, the one on which view event listeners are set. Here is my layout, just so you believe me :

```
<template name="layout">
  <div id="page_container">
    <div id="page_content">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Finally, this is how I am trying to catch the click on the `Cancel` button, which sadly isn't called. Clicking on `#cancel` triggers the form as if the event wasn't caught by Meteor :

```
"click #cancel": function(event, tpl) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Canceled");
},
```

However, I am seeing this event listener on the `#page_content` element, and the popup content is correctly enclosed within `#page_content`.

Here are the relevant HTML screenshots and console output :

**HTML before popup opens :**
[image]

**HTML after popup opens :**
[image]

**Event listeners set on the #page_content element**
[image]

I see very well that the popup is moved when opened/closed, but I don't get why this is preventing the events from being caught up properly, as the event listener is set correctly on `#page_content`, and that the popup content remains within the scope of `#page_content`. My understanding is that events coming from the popup should still bubble up until reaching `#page_content`, and be caught by Meteor's event listeners.

I should add that if I don't enclose the form within a magnificPopup, the events are caught properly by Meteor. Any explanation as to why this is not happening? Any suggestion is most welcome, really.

In the meantime, I'll have to bypass Meteor's logic to set up popup's listeners.

**EDIT**

This is even more troubling but... if I add the class `mfp-close` to the clicked element, and I set my listener on the `.mfp-close` class, everything work as expected...

Comment: cancel shouldn't have input type sbumit: try   <input id="cancel" name="cancel" value="{{_ 'Cancel'}}"/>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I removed it, but this doesn't solves the problem. I'll edit the post to make this more obvious. I should have said somewhere that not enclosing the form within a popup makes the event caught properly. 

Many thanks anyway for this contribution. I'll know now this is a bad practice to assign the type `submit` on a cancel button

Comment: can you try to make the cancel as a link and try. like <a href="" id="cancel" > {{_ 'Cancel'}} </a>

Comment: Sure. I have got to get going but I'll give this a try in a couple of hours.  Thank you for helping out

Comment: Nop... it is not working any better with a link unfortunately. I am facing the same behaviour. The event isn't caught by Meteor